# moving data from one table of databse to another table with shell

Tags: mysql, shell, data-migration

I have two databases in mysql and I want to move data from one table of database1 to one table in database2. These tables have similar schema. I know that I can use this query for inserting data to a table from another.

```
Insert Into table1 (select * from table2)
```

I can do this with command line. The problem is that these tables are from diffrenet databases and I know for reading data from one table, I must choose its database with this sql command

```
use database1;
```

how can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use: `insert Into db1.table1 (select * from db2.table2)`

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use necesarily the `use database1` sentence... You can do the following:

```
insert into database2.table1
select * from database1.table1
```

If you want to use the shell, you may use `mysqldump`. If you are working on Linux (or other unix or unix-like environment), you can use:

```
mysqldump -h [host] -u [user] -p[password] database1 table1 | mysql -h [host] -u [user] -p[password] database2
```

This will make an exact copy of `table1` (which is in `database1`) in `database2`. Just a warning: if you have a table named `table1` in `database2` it will be erased before making the copy.

Hope this helps you